# How do I make an text output in javaSwing

Tags: java

Hi i have made a calculator that uses the console as a input and output which works in eclipse but as expected it doesn't work when compiled. Is there anyway to make a cmd like window that replaces System.print commands and such?

Comment: You mentioned Swing, which would allow you to create a desktop GUI.  No, there's no easy way to simulate a console.

Comment: Nor would you want to as you'd be trying to shove a square peg into a round hole.